# My Android project app is working on honor 8 lite but not working on Mi note 5. Please see the below error

Tags: android

The error I got while installing on Mi note 5

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sissu/com.sissu.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class EditText
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class EditText
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                           at com.sissu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635) 
                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class EditText
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:975)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                           at com.sissu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62) 
                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357) 
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635) 
                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.sissu:drawable/edittext_design" (7f080090) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080090 a=-1 r=0x7f080090}
                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2646)
                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
                                                           at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:388)
                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
                                                           at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:680)
                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:64)
                                                           at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:62)
                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:58)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:975) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                           at com.sissu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62) 
                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357) 
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.j

ava:635)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To build>Generate signed apk.